# Altering a stored procedure during busy times - Can this cause locks and system crashes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, locking

Hi we have a very intensive stored procedure that is called numerous times from our web site during the day.

Would altering this stored proc for performance tuning during peak times cause the system to crash and if so how do you prevent this or monitor that the alter caused the crash in the first place.

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001062/what-happens-if-altering-a-stored-procedure-while-it-is-running

Comment: yeah I saw that answer but does it lock the tables that are in the stored proc? Is it ok to make changes to stored procs on live heavy databases?